# how to read sdef file

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I am trying with `NSArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile_("bla.sdef")` but that returns `None`.

I also tried `NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_("bla.sdef")` but that also returns `None`.

I am trying to get a `NSDictionary` object in the end in a form where parts of it are conforming to the dict for [`NSScriptCommandDescription initWithSuiteName:commandName:dictionary:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScriptCommandDescription_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSScriptCommandDescription).

---

(Note: I don't want to know here how to load scripting definitions into `NSScriptSuiteRegistry`. I really just want to know here how to read the sdef-file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods are for reading property-list files. An sdef file is not a property list; it follows a different, purpose-specific XML schema, defined in [sdef(5)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sdef.5.html).

I don't think there is a public API for reading sdef files directly into a dictionary or more scripting-specific object; you'll need to do it yourself using an XML parser (either one of Cocoa's or one of Python's).